# jQuery with multiple slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few forms that are initially hidden on a page. When a user clicks on a specific link on the page, the corresponding form shows using the jQuery slideToggle. The way that I am doing it right now seems convaluted and there has to be a more succinct way of doing it. Can anyone help me be more efficient in doing this, i.e., less code, best practice, etc.?

```
    // Show & Hide the forms on the "We need your help" page
        jQuery('.contribute-form').hide();
        jQuery('.translate-form').hide();
        // Contribute Form
        jQuery('.contribute').on('click', function(){
            if(jQuery('.translate-form').css('display', 'block')){
                jQuery('.translate-form').slideToggle('slow');
                jQuery('.contribute-form').slideToggle('slow');
            } else if(jQuery('.donate-form').css('display', 'block')){
                jQuery('.donation-form').slideToggle('slow');
                jQuery('.contribute-form').slideToggle('slow');
            } else {
                jQuery('.contribute-form').slideToggle('slow');
            }
        });
        // Translate Form
        jQuery('.translate').on('click', function(){
            if(jQuery('.donate-form').css('display', 'block')){
                jQuery('.donate-form').slideToggle('slow');
                jQuery('.translate-form').slideToggle('slow');
            } else if(jQuery('.contribute-form').css('display', 'block')){
                jQuery('.contribute-form').slideToggle('slow');
                jQuery('.translate-form').slideToggle('slow');
            } else {
                jQuery('.translate-form').slideToggle('slow');
            }
        });
       // Donate Form
        jQuery('.donate').on('click', function(){
            if(jQuery('.translate-form').css('display', 'block')){
                jQuery('.translate-form').slideToggle('slow');
                jQuery('.donate-form').slideToggle('slow');
            } else if(jQuery('.contribute-form').css('display', 'block')){
                jQuery('.contribute-form').slideToggle('slow');
                jQuery('.donate-form').slideToggle('slow');
            } else {
                jQuery('.donate-form').slideToggle('slow');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the dollar alias for cleaner code. Then, combine selectors in single statements. Finally, use the `is()` method with `:visible` rather than fiddling with CSS.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.contribute').on('click', function(){
        if ( $('.translate-form').is(':visible') ) {
            $('.translate-form, .contribute-form').slideToggle('slow');
        } else if ( $('.donate-form').is(':visible') ) {
            $('.donation-form, .contribute-form').slideToggle('slow');
        } else {
            $('.contribute-form').slideToggle('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm sure your logic could be simplified further using classes and DOM traversal. If you'd like to put your code in a demo at http://jsfiddle.net we could offer more suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! That looks good to me. I guess I should have mentioned that I am developing on Wordpress and that is the reason for using `jQuery` vs `$` . Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wrapping the code in a jQuery function like I did allows you to use the dollar alias like I have here.

Comment: I will totally use that from now on! Thank you for helping me make this easier.